# Android align contents of a table

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm struggling to get the contents of a table cell to align left/right.  My code is:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_one"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/button_one" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_two"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/button_two" />
</TableRow>
....
```

I'd like the 2 ImageButton's to fit snuggly together in the middle but at the moment there is a gap - it looks like each cell is centering the contents.  The table expands to the full size of the screen and there are 4 rows in total the same as above.  I want the image buttons to resize to fill the screen whilst maintaining their aspect ratio.

I've tried setting the gravity on the image buttons but it doesn't seem to work (it moves it by a few pixels only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, changing the scaleType to "fitEnd" and "fitStart" appears to have done the trick.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_one"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:src="@drawable/button_one" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_two"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/button_two" />
```

....

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `android:layout_width="0dp"` on the buttons, which will allow the layout weights to function, making each button split the available space equally.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work.  I think it's maybe because I'm also scaling the buttons that's causing it some confusion.